# Two SVG elements in XAML display different sizes, despite same height and width request

Tags: css, wpf, xaml, svg

I have the following XAML, in xamarin using [this](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/SVG) plugin to display SVG files. The second image is much bigger than the first. I believe it is to do with the scaling in the SVG files? I can't set `height` or `width` directly as these are `read-only in this binding`. How can I fix this?

[image: Different size]

```
<abstractions:SvgImage Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}" SvgPath="{Binding Facebook_Round}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
<abstractions:SvgImage Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}" SvgPath="{Binding Google_Round}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

The SVG Facebook First Tag:

```
<svg xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" height="300" width="300" version="1.1" fill-opacity="0"> xml:space="preserve">
```

The SVG Google First Tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 486.392 486.392" width="300" height="300" >
```

Comment: Pretty sure they are actually the same size only one of them is only got things rendered in the top left corner. If you gave the first one a viewBox of say viewBox="0 0 150 150" that would probably fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `width` and `height` **CSS** properties on your `svg` tags will scale them down or up to any size.

In your particular case, the difference is created by the `viewbox` attribute of the Google tag: `viewBox="0 0 486.392 486.392"`.

However, instead of removing it, you should just wrap your `svg`s in some container and apply:

```
.someContainer svg {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
}
```

Of course, `3em` is just an example. The important part is **the `path`s will be scaled to fit the CSS dimensions of the `svg` element**. Most of the times, you should only specify one dimension to avoid distortion: `height` when they are aligned horizontally or `width` when they form a column.

Comment: I am not using these SVGs with CSS. Is there any way, either in XAML or directly in the SVG to make both of these files draw an image that is exactly the same size?

Comment: `style="height: 3em;"` on each of the svg's should do it.

Comment: I already have the height and width attributes set to "300" in my svg tag, should that be in addition to those?

Comment: That is relative to the viewbox, in arbitrary units. Those units have nothing to do with any measurable units inside your document. You need to specify a unit the browser understands: `px`, `em`, `vh`, `%`, but not in the `height` `svg` property, but in its `CSS` `height` property. `height="300"` is not the same as `style="height:300px"`.

Comment: Why have you tagged your question with `CSS` if you're not willing to use a `CSS` solution? The other option is to redraw all your paths using the same `viewBox` size, but the paths have to be scaled accordingly. There are probably tools for it.